# Unreadable Greek text in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, browser, text, translation, symbols

In my Chrome browser I want to read the below Greek text and it's unreadable. Also tried Firefox and it's the same.

How can I read this Greek text in my browsers, or at least translate them in Word and be able to read it?

ŒïœÖœáŒ±œÅŒπœÉœÑŒøœçŒºŒµ. Œü ŒªŒøŒ≥Œ±œÅŒπŒ±œÉŒºœå œÉŒ±œÇ Œ≠œáŒµŒπ œÄŒπœÉœÑœâŒ∏ŒµŒØ ŒµœÄŒπœÑœÖœáœéœÇ ŒºŒµ 41.00ŒµœÖœÅœé.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Greek, probably you have an encoding error

Comment: I am sure it is Greek. If you have a way to translate them I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You mean that the text you pasted above are Greek letters? I can assure you that they are not. Maybe your question is 'why I cannot see the Greek letters in Chrome?' If this is the case just try to switch chrome's encoding as descreibed http://googlechrometutorial.com/google-chrome-initial-settings/Google-chrome-page-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to read UTF-8 as an 8-bit encoding for Greek (perhaps, Windows-1253). Try changing the page encoding in your browser.